# Execute anonymous(Eclipse), Developer console and Query editor

Tags: permissions, eclipse, developer-console, execute-anonymous

Does the `Query Editor` or `Execute Anonymous` (either via the `Eclipse IDE` or the `Developer Console`) run in System Mode or User Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit of searching around for official reference, and there is one in the `Apex Developer Guide` - [Using the with sharing or without sharing Keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm):

> In system context, Apex code has access to all objects and fields— object permissions, field-level security, sharing rules aren’t applied for the current user. This is to ensure that code won’t fail to run because of hidden fields or objects for a user. The only exceptions to this rule are Apex code that is executed with the `executeAnonymous` call and Chatter in Apex. `executeAnonymous` always executes using the full permissions of the current user. For more information on `executeAnonymous`, see [Anonymous Blocks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_anonymous_block.htm).

Comment: You said "executeAnonymous always executes using the full permissions of the current user. " What is the meaning of full permission in context of current user ? It means user will treat like system admin profile(Full permission) in executeAnonymous ?

Comment: No, the permissions of the ***current user***, not the permissions of an admin.

Answer (score 2):

It is running in User Mode:

> In Salesforce, all apex code run in system mode. It ignores user's
>   permissions. Only exception is anonymous blocks like developer console
>   and standard controllers.

Quote from http://aluniya.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/salesforce-system-mode-user-mode-and.html

Since I didn't find similar description in official documents, I have tested it myself and it proves out it is user mode.

Comment: Can you link to this reference?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I didn't see that in official documents. Only see it in personal blogs and some community discussions. That's why I tested it.

Comment: Still, you're clearly quoting *something*. It might be better to convey that more explicitly is all I'm saying, and if that includes clarifying the uncertain voracity, so be it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Edited and added the reference.